# How do i close a bootstrap popup from code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, devexpress

I want to be able to dismiss a modal from an asp.button so i used the following

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSaveDetails" Text="Save Details" CssClass="btn-primary-purple" OnClick="btnSaveDetails_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false"  data-dismiss="modal" />
```

But i noticed that my .net controls inside the btnSaveDetails_Click event is not getting updated cause its no longer acting like a submit button what is my best way to close a modal but yet still allow my code behind to get the the updated values from the controls the div of the modal is as such.

```
 <div id="edit-detail">
    <div class="popupBox popbox-wide">
        <form role="form" data-toggle="validator" id="editform" class="form-pop-wide">
            <span id="close-pop" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" onclick="editdetails_hide()" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <h2>Edit Details</h2>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group form-group full-length edit-form-group">
                           <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="address1"  NullText="Address 1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>

                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group form-group full-length edit-form-group">
                              <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="address2" NullText="Address 2" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>

                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group form-group full-length edit-form-group">
                              <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="town" NullText="Town" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group form-group full-length edit-form-group">
                                     <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="region" NullText="Region" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group form-group full-length edit-form-group">
                                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="country" NullText="Country" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group form-group full-length edit-form-group">
                                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="postcode" NullText="Post Code" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group form-group full-length edit-form-group">

                               <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="mob" NullText="Mobile"   CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group form-group full-length edit-form-group">

                               <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="phone"  NullText="Day Phone"  CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <br />
               <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSaveDetails" Text="Save Details" CssClass="btn-primary-purple" OnClick="btnSaveDetails_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false"  data-dismiss="modal" />


        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whole concept doesn't make sense. The modal exists in browser not at server. Use documented javascript methods for the modal to close it

Comment: Charlietfl is correct and if it looks like your button is closing a modal it might be that btnSaveDetails is just posting back the form to the server. Also for your button to call btnSaveDetails_Click() at server side, asp:Button tag must be placed into a runat="server" **form** tag. The form you have is client side.